using MSE loss paired with F-score in a classification model
for a video summarization project i use the features of each frame as input to predict if some of these frames are included in the summary or not.
one of the famous implementations i found had treated this task as a regression task but it used a sigmoid output with f-score as evaluation metric and MSE loss.
the problem is that i have read online that MSE_Loss is only used for regression tasks when the target is continuous set of numbers.

target values in this case are scores of the frames from 0.0 to 1.0 and the predictions are also
set of probability distributions for each video.

fscore is then derived by doing a knapsack to pick the best representative group of scores convert them to 1's and the other groups are converted to 0's
then it is compared with a binary summary.
my question is it wrong to use MSE in such case as it clearly looks like a classification problem not a regression one unless i don't really have full understanding of the relation between regression and this task.

It is difficult to advise on model evaluation without knowing what is important from an application perspective.  Why is F1 relevant, that is normally for detection problems rather than classification tasks?

@DikranMarsupial i can provide more details if needed although i dont quite understand your question.

basically we need to know how the classifier will be used, are there unequal misclassification costs (e.g false positives worse than false negatives), do you need a hard classification or do you need a probability or a ranking of examples, do you need a reject option, is the relative frequency of classes in operation different to those in the dataset.  These are all issues that might influence which performance metrics are important.  F1 ignores "true negatves", so you wouldn't want to use that where the classes are symmetric e.g. Cat or dog in images.

@DikranMarsupial task itself is video summarization with the inputs are sequences of features and the labels are binary arrays with 15% or 20% True values that represent the summary of the video
the model predicts a probability distribution based on the features of each frame
[ .443,.345,.342,....,.877] then these probabilities are processed with the changepoints in video like video segments to give scores to each segment and finally use a (knapsack w/ 15-20 proportion) to keep the most representative segments in the final summary with true values and the unwanted ones with false values.

Then the F-score is computed between the final summary and the original labels that are 15%-20% of the original video. I have no problem with the f-score as it seems suitable in this case; however, I was told otherwise in the case of MSE, so I was confused. Also, the extra processing step after prediction got me confused; is that a regression task or a classification task?

I agree with Stephan that MSE is a perfectly reasonable performance metric for classification tasks.  I quite often use the Least-Squares Support Vector Machine (or equivalently kernel ridge regression or kernel fisher discriminant classifier) where the training criterion is the MSE on the class labels.  It is a useful metric.

The MSE is absolutely appropriate. It is a proper scoring rule (also known as the Brier score), i.e., a loss function for probabilistic predictions that rewards calibrated predictions, i.e., ones that are "correct".
Hard 0-1 classifications are far inferior. Any probabilistic prediction on one side of your threshold will give you the same hard 0-1 classification, but it makes a difference whether an instance has a probability of 0.001 or 0.01 or 0.1 to be of the target class.
A few related threads (the F1 score suffers from the exact same issues as accuracy):

Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?
Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?
Classification probability threshold
Why is LogLoss preferred over other proper scoring rules? which discusses the Brier score, which per above is just the MSE of the probabilistic predictions


"Hard 0-1 classifications are far inferior." this depends on the needs of the application, which we don't know.  However even for tasks where a specific threshold is important, it is a a good idea to assess the probabilities as well, via MSE/Brier/Log loss. (+1)
